# How to disable the sticky header using CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making this website where I would like to disable the sticky header but the theme doesn't provide an option to do that and the theme doesn't add a class once the menu is sticky. I've tried changing position:absolute but it's not working.
My last hope now is using JS to add a class to the header once the site is scrolled and than just disabling the menu but I'm not sure on how to accomplish that.

Here's the link to the site: https://vectormsp.co.uk/

This is header wrapper, I've tried changing the position to absolute but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#headerwrap {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How did you try? Can you edit theme's CSS?

Comment: I tried by using Inspect Element in Chrome and by adding custom CSS. I took a look at the themes CSS but I couldn't find the part about the menu.

Comment: When you inspect the element you can see where was defined, file and line, go there to edit its rules.

Answer (score 0):

just change `fixed` to `relative`

```
     #headerwrap {
         position: relative;
     }
```

Comment: body #headerwrap { ... } add body at start and still doesn't then you can use !important too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if(window.scrollY==0){
 console.log("User is at the top of the page!")
}
```

So to add a class to an element with Javascript when the user is at the top of the page you can use something like:

```
let header = document.getElementById("headerwrap")
if(window.scrollY==0){
    header.classList.add("NAME-OF-CLASS-TO-ADD");
}
else {
    header.classList.remove("NAME-OF-CLASS-TO-REMOVE");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it seems that the scrolling returns a negative value.

Comment: The scrolling in the theme you are using is a bit weird. It won't work with that method. What is the name of the theme you are using?

Comment: The theme is Fullpane from Themify.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the sticky header using JavaScript, you can add an event listener to the window's scroll event. When the user scrolls, you can check the scroll position, and if it exceeds a certain threshold, add a class to the header to disable the sticky behavior.

Here's an example of how you could achieve this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Get the header element
  var header = document.getElementById("header-wrapper");

  // Define the scroll threshold (adjust as needed)
  var scrollThreshold = 100;

  // Function to handle the scroll event
  function handleScroll() {
    // Check the scroll position
    var scrollPosition = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    // Add or remove a class based on the scroll position
    if (scrollPosition > scrollThreshold) {
      header.classList.add("disable-sticky");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("disable-sticky");
    }
  }

  // Attach the scroll event listener
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});
```

the script waits for the DOM to be fully loaded, gets the header element by its ID ("header-wrapper"), defines a scroll threshold (100 pixels in this case), and adds a class ("disable-sticky") to the header when the scroll position exceeds the threshold. You can adjust the scroll threshold according to your needs.

Make sure to add the corresponding CSS to style the header when the "disable-sticky" class is applied. For example:

```
.disable-sticky {
  position: relative !important; /* Adjust the positioning as needed */
}
```

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Comment: No, I am developer specially in Backend with PHP and Laravel